# Load multiple XML from web library using C#

Tags: c#, xml

Need to load and save multiple XML files from multiple links that have different identifiers.
for example:

**load from:**

```
http:/...identifier=1
http:/...identifier=2
...
http:/...identifier=m
```

**save as:**

```
file_1_1.xml
file_1_2.xml
file_2_1.xml
...
file_n_m.xml
```

**XML looks like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <OAI-PMH xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
      <responseDate>...</responseDate>
      <request verb="GetRecord" identifier="1"</request>
      <GetRecord>
        <record>
          <header>
            <identifier>1</identifier>
            <datestamp>...</datestamp>
          </header>
          <metadata>
            <P3DM xmlns="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
              <MODELINFOID>1</MODELINFOID>
              <TITLE>Roth</TITLE>
  ....
```

**code looks like:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var i = 1;
    do
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(args[0] + "/?verb=GetRecord&metadataPrefix=p3dm&identifier=" + i);
        var node = doc.Descendants("identifier");
        foreach (var n in node)
        {
            doc.Save("file_" + i + "_" + n.Value + ".xml");
        }
    } while (i < 5);
}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking? You are trying to save the individual xml files to disk?

Comment: Yes, sorry cause I didn't mention. I can save files without n.Value and foreach loop, it seem I'm doing something wrong with Descendants.

Comment: then your answer is below but I can't help feeling there is a different point to your question that we haven't quite got to? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - so NOW understanding that you want to 'process' something in the xml files rather than saving them...

Having taken another look at the code I suspect it is the xml namespace causing you the trouble.

If you replace `var node = doc.Descendants("identifier");` with:

```
var node = doc.Descendants()
    .Where(d=>d.Name.LocalName=="identifier");
```

I'm sure you will fare better...

Answer (score 0):

Trying my best with what you've said... If you only want to download and save the xml files then you have no need to interrogate them with the `XDocument` object?

Just download them with a `WebClient` object -  amend your code to something like this:

```
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

var i=1;
do
{
    string url = args[0] + "/?verb=GetRecord&metadataPrefix=p3dm&identifier=" + i);
    string destFilePath = @"C:\file" + i +".xml";

    webClient.DownloadFile(url,destFilePath);

} while (i < 5);
```

Comment: I don't need to save it at all, this save thing is just for testing. Actually, I need to load files, and than write output.xml which uses all loaded files and calculate things with elements of these files. Sorry if I'm not so clear and thanks for response.

Comment: Why this don't work?

Comment: @Mrvoje It's dissapointing that I asked you to confirm that you needed only to save the files in the comments to the original question, you confirmed this, I gave the answer and THEN you said "nope, nothing to do with saving the files". Furthermore you the edited the original comment confirming that you only wanted to save the files to say something different! Not the best way to solicit good will and assistance if I may say so. New answer below...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wanted to make your job easier. As I sad before, I'm new in this so it's all bit confusing. Sorry again and thanks.